# Excel parent list chain

Tags: excel

I have a large table of two columns in Excel 2010.  Column A is the user, column B is the person who invited the user.  Usernames are alphanumeric, including some which are just numeric.  The earliest users don't have an invitee.

```
User | Parent
-------------
AAA  |
BBB  |
CCC  | AAA
DDD  | BBB
EEE  | DDD
FFF  | DDD
GGG  | FFF
HHH  |
III  | GGG
```

What I would like to do is have a formula which allows me to go to grandparent (and great-grand-parent, and beyond), so I'm trying to find a formula-based solution which uses mixed relative and absolute columns where appropriate.

The above chain would go to a maximum of four, but I have reason to believe my data set goes to no more than 20 levels deep at maximum.  I would like to find a formula or combination of formulas that get me to this (and, as I said, beyond):

```
USER | PARENT | P2  | P3  | P4  | ...
AAA  |        |
BBB  |        |
CCC  | AAA    |
DDD  | BBB    |
EEE  | DDD    | BBB |
FFF  | DDD    | BBB |
GGG  | FFF    | DDD | BBB
HHH  |
III  | GGG    | FFF | DDD | BBB
...
```

I've tried various methods combining VLOOKUP, MATCH, and INDEX commands, with and without a key row of user ID numbers (since some of those solutions without a numeric column broke down when faced with the fact that "0" was a valid username, which makes error trapping more difficult).  I can get to P2 pretty reliably, but I can't ever seem to get to P3 without it breaking down.  Incidentally, the formulas I've tried are very CPU-intensive, given the data goes to nearly 400,000 rows, but calculation time doesn't concern me much.  My brute-force methods aren't working.  There are several somewhat similar questions on stackoverflow, but they're asking for slightly different things, and I haven't been able to adapt any of them.

If this can be done via standard functions, that would be preferable to VBA (which I am not familiar with), even if the calculation time is longer, as it would increase my ability to maintain it when I need to revisit this issue next year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C5,UserParent,2,FALSE) & "","")`, replacing `UserParent` with your absolutely referenced column pair (e.g. `$B$5:$C$30`) or an appropriate named range.  Copy it down and across your grandparent columns.

I'm betting this is the approach that you tried before, but you end up with a bunch of zeroes in the output.  The juicy bit in this formula is the `& ""`.  This forces the empty cells in your parent column to be treated as empty strings rather that zero-valued cells when `VLOOKUP` does its work.  This removes all those zeroes that dork up the output.

I was able to make it work with a bunch of random alphanumerics, but without sample data, this is the best I could do.

Comment: This is working well.  It doesn't handle a few weird usernames correctly (those which consist only of question mark characters or numerals), but nothing a few minutes of minor cleanup can't get around.  Given the amount of data here, that is entirely reasonable and a big improvement over what I was getting.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As you have noted, the existence of 0 as a valid username, is a real problem - since this also gets returned as a value by `VLOOKUP()` (and equivalently by `INDEX(,MATCH())`) for names with no parents.

An alternative strategy is to use some dummy value which does not appear in either the User or Parent column, such as -99999, to signify the absent parent and to add this in place of any empty cell in the Parent column of the User/Parent table. Also add a row to this table with this same dummy value in both the User and Parent columns. Now you will only get a zero returned by VLOOKUP if 0 is genuinely the parent of the cell whose parent you are attempting to find. You will detect when there are no more "levels" when all the values in the column are equal to the dummy value.